# custom password textfield in android studio programmatically

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragments

how can I make a custom password textfield like the picture in android programmatically java ? (or XML)
Im only interested to the textfield (the keyboard is android's system)
thank you

[Password TextField Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i2BhY.png)

[image]

Comment: Hi Mourad, I don't think this is a [EditText](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText), its a custom view. Take a look at this guide on how to make one - https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components - or, you can also make it using Compound view that makes use of existing view available in Android - see this guide to have some idea - https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidCustomViews/article.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Import library in app.gralde

```
implementation 'com.poovam:pin-edittext-field:1.2.3'
```

XML layout for password field

```
<com.poovam.pinedittextfield.CirclePinField
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="text"
    app:noOfFields="4"                                                
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textSelectHandle="@drawable/text_handle" 
    app:circleRadius="15dp"               
    app:fillerRadius="2dp" 
    app:fillerColor="@color/colorPrimary" 
    app:fieldBgColor="#ddd"
    android:id="@+id/circleField"/>
```

**Reference** : https://github.com/poovamraj/PinEditTextField

Answer (score 0):

I think this library can help you. It's easy and simple.
https://github.com/alphamu/PinEntryEditText

**You just go to that link and follow the steps.**

[image]